# Binding to Global variable in Silverlight for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

Let's say that I have a global variable defined in App.xaml.cs as follows:

```
public static MyClass GlobalInstance = new MyClass()
```

And then in MainPage.xaml I would like to bind to a property of this class like follows:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding App.GlobalInstance.Property1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80">
```

Is there something I am missing here? For some reason it does not appear to be properly bound.

Any advice here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign your App to DataContext of the page

First way is do this in page constructor:

```
 public MainPage()
 {
     InitializeComponent();

     DataContext = App.Current;
 }
```

And your binding will be

```
 {Binding GlobalInstance.Property1}
```

The second way is to make a reference to App class in page resources

Also, edit your field implementation to something like this:

```
 public static MyClass GlobalInstance {get; private set; }

 ...
 GlobalInstance = new MyClass();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Ku6opr, my issue was something entirely unexpected. I was creating a new instance of my GlobalInstance, and just needed to set the DataContext again after creating the new instance...